# Lambda assuming AWS IAM role with fine-grained permissions

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-sts

I am trying to assume fine-grained DynamoDB access based on information attached to an Amazon Cognito user.

The current architecture is as such:

1. React-Native app calls a http get, passing the JWT as the Authorization header to get through an AWS Api Gateway.
2. The lambda function on the receiving end decodes the JWT and pulls out the Role Arn attached to the Cognito group the user belongs to.
3. The lambda function then calls sts.assumeRole with the RoleArn mentioned above, a RoleSessionName with various bits of user information, and an in-line policy to limit database access based on a custom attribute attached to said Cognito user.

After this set of events I would hope the Scan I am calling against the database would fail due to a lack of permissions to access certain elements (a Query will be used later instead of a scan, I simply want to make sure the permissions are working correctly).

However the scan continues to get all items from the database.

I must be missing something simple, this is the method I've read about for doing this type of action.

This is the role we're assuming in the Lambda function:

```
CognitoGroupRole:
 Type: AWS::IAM::Role
 Properties:
  Description: Cognito Assets Group Role
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          AWS:
            - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root'
        Action:
          - 'sts:AssumeRole'
  Policies:
    - PolicyName: Database1AccessPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "dynamodb:Scan"
              - "dynamodb:PutItem"
              - "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
              - "dynamodb:Query"
            Resource: !GetAtt Database1.Arn
    - PolicyName: Database2AccessPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "dynamodb:Query"
            Resource: !GetAtt Database2.Arn
```

This is the function inside the Lambda which assumes the role and writes the in-line policy:

```
const assumeGroupRole = () => {
    /* Get JWT from event.headers.Authorization */
    const {
      headers: { Authorization },
    } = event;
    /* Get the function name from context.functionName */
    const { functionName } = context;
    /* Decode the JWT */
    const decodedToken = jwt_decode(Authorization);
    const Policy = JSON.stringify({
      Version: '2012-10-17',
      Statement: {
        Effect: 'Allow',
        Action: ['dynamodb:Query', 'dynamodb:Scan'] /* Scan only for testing */,
        Resource /* Device table ARN from environment variables */,
        Condition: {
          /* This condition *should* mean they can only access any row where the leading key is the AccountUniqueId */
          'ForAllValues:StringEquals': {
            'dynamodb:LeadingKeys': [decodedToken['custom:AccountUniqueId']],
          },
        },
      },
    });
    console.info('Inline Policy', Policy);
    /* ARN of the role attached to the cognito group */
    const [RoleArn] = decodedToken['cognito:roles'];
    /* Create session name from the email and function name */
    const RoleSessionName = `${decodedToken.email}+${
      functionName.split('-')[2]
    }`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sts.assumeRole({ RoleArn, RoleSessionName, Policy }, function (
        err,
        data,
      ) {
        if (err) reject(console.error('Assume role error', err, err.stack));
        else resolve(data);
      });
    });
  };
```

Where I actually run the Scan (Query after I get this working) to get the data from the DynamoDB:

```
/* Create new DynamoDB Document client with Credentials from 
 assumeRole */
  const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    accessKeyId: Credentials.AccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: Credentials.SessionToken,
  });

  const params = {
    TableName,
  };

  try {
    /* Query the database with the above parameters to fetch only the 
    items that match the conditions */
    const { Items } = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
    console.info('Queried Items', Items);
    const statusCode = 200;
    const body = JSON.stringify(Items);
    logEvents(statusCode, body);
    return {
      statusCode,
      body,
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.info('Error', e);
    const statusCode = 400;
    const body = JSON.stringify(e.message);
    logEvents(statusCode, body);
    return {
      statusCode,
      body,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Where do you actually run the query, use the data returned by assumeRole?

Comment: Edited my original post to show the requested information.

Comment: If you make a call to `sts:GetCallerIdentity`, what does it return? What ARN/user is it?

Comment: It might be behave like this because an inline policy must be a subset of the main policy. Your main policy and the inline policy do not have the same condition so the inline might be ignored. I've never tested it before but it might be worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses.  I ended up figuring this out through casual conversation with a co-worker.

As it turns out the "scan" call ignores those types of fine-grained permissions.  I'm assuming this is because scan is not looking for a sub-set of the data but rather just all the data.

With the same code posted above with a non-matching `AccountUniqueId` the query returns a "not-authorized" error.  When I use the correct `AccountUniqueId` I get the data I would expect.